# "challenge for" VS "challenge with"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. One of the main challenges *with* advanced knee and ankle devices is the development of a robust sealing system for their hydraulic cylinders.
> 2. One of the main challenges *for* advanced knee and ankle devices is the development of a robust sealing system for their hydraulic cylinders.

When we are talking about challenges facing advanced kee and anke devices, which proposition is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

The use of **with** in sentence 1 indicates that the challenge arises with the use of these devices. It's another way of saying **arising from** or **presented by**.

That's to say that the devices present a challenge because their sealing system is not robust. They don't work as well as they ought to.

The sentence does not specify who is challenged although it implies that the challenge is to (or **for**) the designers, developers, manufacturers etc.

The use of **for** in the second sentence is incorrect.

It implies that the devices themselves are being challenged. This is clearly not the case. The challenge is to (or **for**) the people who produce them.